# Higher exponent in pow reduces instructions in shader?

Tags: hlsl

When I compile an HLSL shader with `pow(foo, 6)` or `pow(foo, 8)`, the compiler creates assembly that has about 10 more instructions than if I create the same shader with `pow(foo, 9)` or `pow(foo,10)` or `pow(foo,7)`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instructions or instruction *slots*?

The `pow` instruction takes three 3 slots, whereas the `mul` instruction takes only 1.

(Reference: instruction sets for: [vs_2_0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172936(v=vs.85).aspx), [ps_2_0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219852(v=vs.85).aspx), [vs_3_0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172938(v=vs.85).aspx), [ps_3_0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219854(v=vs.85).aspx))

When you are writing a shader you generally want to keep the instruction slot count down, because you have a limited number of instruction slots as defined by the shader model. It is also a reasonable way to approximate the computational complexity of your shader (ie: how fast it will run).

A power of 1 is obviously a no-op. A power of 2 requires one `mul` instruction. Powers of 3 and 4 can be done with two `mul` instructions. Powers of 5, 6, and 8 can be done with three `mul` instructions.

(I imagine the math behind this optimisation is explained by the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) that Jim Lewis posted.)

The likely reason the compiler is choosing three `mul` instructions over a single `pow` instruction (both use the same number of instruction slots) is that the `pow` instruction with a constant exponent will also require the allocation of a constant register to store that exponent. Obviously using up three instruction slots and no constant registers is better than using up three slots and one constant register.

(Why you are getting *10* more instructions? I am not sure, it will depend on your shader code. The HLSL compiler does many weird and wonderful things in the name of optimisation.)

If you use the shader compiler (`fxc`) in the DirectX SDK with the options `/Cc /Fc output.html`, it will give you a nice assembly reading you can examine, including a count of the number of instruction slots used.

Comment: What about power less than 1?

Answer (score 1):

It might be doing some sort of [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) optimization, where the number of operations depends on the number of bits set to 1 in the exponent, and their positions.  (That doesn't quite match what you're describing, though: you'd expect powers of two to be more efficient than exponents with more bits set, in a pure square-and-multiply implementation.)